# UIAccessibility implementation on UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiaccessibility

I am trying to understand how UITableView accessibility works (in order to add the support to some other libraries that work in a similar way). So I implemented *UIAccessibilityContainer Protocol* in *MyTableView* subclass of UITableView.

First of all I need to render the dataSource accessible:

```
- (id<UITableViewDataSource>)dataSource
{
    return (id<UITableViewDataSource>)[self valueForKey:@"_dataSource"];
}
```

Then I reimplement:

```
- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element
{
    return [[self indexPathForCell:element] row];
}

- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount
{
    return [[self dataSource] tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:0];
}
```

and accessibility still works as supposed. Last step would be to implement *- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index*:

```
- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [[self dataSource] tableView:self cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
}
```

But apparently adding this method accessibility for the tableview stops working and I get just a VoiceOver "empty list" when navigating (with voiceover) to the tableview. Funny thing cells are returned properly and I get loads of *AX ERROR: Could not find my mock parent, most likely I am stale.*

I am trying to investigate, I'll post results unless someone comes up with ideas sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Implement those UIAccessibilityProtocal methods inside the UITableviewVell Class. Make the Cell accessible and check.